# Using Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to read data from an excel sheet and form a dictionary in a loop as below.

```
for row in range(2,sheet.max_row+1):
    temp_list.clear()
    for col in range (2,sheet.max_column):
        temp_list.append(sheet.cell(row,col).value)    
    dict_key = sheet.cell(row,1).value
Create a dictionary
   MyDataDictionary.update( {dict_key : temp_list})
```

Assuming my excel have two rows of data I am reading, my dictionary value always gets overwritten with the value from second row always

Comment: Rather than using `MyDataDictionary.update`, you can do `MyDataDictionary[dict_key] = temp_list`, this will add the new key. And if you are using columns for key names, then of course your data will be overwritten, as it has the same key name.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this below:

```
if MyDataDictionary.get(dict_key, []):
    #updates the existing key assuming that temp_list is always a list
    MyDataDictionary.get(dict_key).extend(temp_list)
else:
    #creates a new key
    MyDataDictionary.update({dict_key : temp_list})
```

Comment: The code started to work when I initialized temp_list=[]  instead of using temp_list.clear(). Earlier, my dictionary got updated to blanks everytime I called temp_list.clear().

Answer (score 0):

(Create a dictionary) if this is part of your code what i think is your dictionary is getting created each time you run the loop therefore you should create dictionary before running loop and then update it

Comment: The "Create Dictionary" was meant as a comment only, dictionary was initialised before the loop.  The code started to work when I change the temp_list initialising method from temp_list.clear()  to temp_list =[] .  Trying to figure out the difference between the two options.